Facebook Page Plugin: Posts Duplicating After a Certain Number - How to Resolve?
I've integrated the Facebook Page Plugin into my web application using React, aiming to display posts from a specific Facebook page. However, after a certain number of posts (around 5-7), the posts start duplicating.
I'm using https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-facebook-plugin this plugin in react
My expectation was that the Facebook Page Plugin would render posts from the specified page without duplication, displaying a continuous feed of unique posts as expected.
I'm seeking guidance on potential causes of this duplication problem and any suggested solutions or best practices to ensure the accurate rendering of posts from the Facebook page within the web application. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
